# HP F370 - All lights are on & stable, printer not responding

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

My printer HP F370 isn't working. When I power it on, all the lights namely Power, Error (Paper                                                                                                & Ink), Page Count, Paper Type (Plain paper as well as Photo)                                                                                                light up.

Ideally, after the initial setting up, only Power, Paper Count, Paper Type (either Plain or Photo) should light up.

Now, the printer isn't responding at all, although Windows is still able to detect it.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a copier/printer? If it is, attempt to make a copy of something without using your computer. If it prints, then its not the printer. If it doesn't, unplug and replug into wall outlet and retry printing.

Also make sure that all of your cables are connected (to the computer of coarse).

At this point, it would be the print spooler. Reinstall the printer software on your computer and retry printing.

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, it is an All in One. The printer is not responding at all. I'm not able to copy. 
Even when I open up the door on the front to access the cartridges, the cartridges are not coming out in front which they ideally should.

Comment: Did you try to unplug and replug it in? (power cord)

Comment: Yes I did. Can it be a power cord / circuit board failure?

Comment: Yes. At this point it is most definitely your circuit board (not your power cord, because the printer wouldn't even turn on /unless its your transformer/). Unless you are holding on to this printer for its accounting value, or because you have found it to be excessively reliable in the past, you should probably let it go. **Unless**, you find someone who knows how to fix printers. Good luck with your excursion! (if you found my answer to be helpful, please upvote or confirm it) Thank you.

Comment: Time for iFixit!!! :)

Comment: Good luck, I don't think they'll tell you how to fix the circuit board?!